# Python to search a string in file and assign to below lines to variable

Tags: python

I have to search for a string in a file and assign the next 3 lines to variables var1, var2, var3

I have tried below code:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if 'Ball' in line:
        a = (''.join(islice(f, 1)))
        b = (''.join(islice(f, 2)))
```

In above code it searches for Ball in the test file and assigns the next line to variable a

and for b I need to assign second line output but i am getting two lines output.

Please help

Comment: Do you can just assign second line to variable b right?

Comment: yes, after  search string second line to variable b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated for new variation of the question**

You are getting 2 lines assigned to `b` because you are asking `islice()` to give you 2 lines by passing `2` as the value for the `end` argument. You could do it like this:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Ball' in line:
            var1 = ''.join(islice(f, 1))
            var2 = ''.join(islice(f, 1))
            var3 = ''.join(islice(f, 1))
```

which takes *one* line at a time using `islice()`. It's nicer to use `next()` for this though:

```
var1 = next(f)
var2 = next(f)
var3 = next(f)
```

A more succinct way, still using `islice()`, is this:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Ball' in line:
            var1, var2, var3 = islice(f, 3)
```

which reads the next 3 lines and assigns them to the variables `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`.

---

**Original answer to original question**

The problem is that the first for loop consumes the entire file before the second for loop is entered. That second loop terminates immediately because all lines of the have already been read.

Try adding a `break` in the first loop after assigning to `a`.

```
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Ball' in line:
            a = (''.join(islice(f, 1)))
            break

    for line in f:
        if 'Bat' in line:
            b = (''.join(islice(f, 2)))
```

`break` will terminate the first loop once the line following the one containing `Ball` is found. Then the second for loop can continue processing the file on the next line if there is one.

If you only need the second of the two lines after `Bat` you can pass `start` to `islice()`:

```
   for line in f:
       if 'Bat' in line:
           b = islice(f, 1, 2)
```

This works because the default start is `0` so specifying `1` skips the first line.

Comment: @asteroid4u: I've updated my answer to address your revised question

Answer (score 1):

A key idea to understand is that `f` below is an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-iterable). The effect which often surprises novices is that you can only go through the lines once due to how iterators work (they raise a special exception when they are "finished" and don't reset). However, we don't have to consume the whole iterator. In the code below, I stop when I find the string, and the iterator is not yet completely consumed. I can then consume the next three lines by explicitly calling `f.next()`. I could also have had another loop which would continue where the last one left off. Note for simplicity I have left out error checking (what would happen if the file didn't contain `Ball`?

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
   # First scan for 'Ball'
   for line in f:
       if 'Ball' in line:
           break
   # next three lines into variables
   var1 = f.next()
   var2 = f.next()
   var3 = f.next()
```

Comment: If Ball does not exit in file my variables get empty input. Then i will tell there are no entries